# Voicemail not working on my iPhone I

Tags: voicemail

I’m a Sprint customer and I changed my network to T-Mobile at the T-Mobile store.  Since then my voicemail is not available. I setup my voicemail at the store and when I try to retrieve my voicemail it asks me to set a password and greeting?

Comment: Voicemail is entirely down to your provider. Give them a call. You cannot fix it from your end.

Comment: Both of these comments belong as answers and I’ll see about voting to close as a duplicate. I believe we may already have many answers explaining where Apple support ends and where carrier support begins. That question is very on-topic IMO and functionally equivalent to this question as worded.